# "Format" of time announcements

Tags: time, voice

Running latest update of Catalina, but this issue has existed for at least two years.

If I turn on "announce time," what I hear is "it is now (integer) hours."  Is there a way to make it say "it is now (integer) o'clock like 99% of en_US speakers would say?  Even the pseudo-military "ten hundred hours" would be better than what I'm getting.